# How to add item into HashMap by method

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to add some item from the class `DisplayCard` to the hashMap `displayCardMap` by the method. 
The output of hashmap to look like

> brand: modelNumber: memorySize

Then I create some method to help me.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ComputerShop {

    Map <String, Double> displayCardMap = new HashMap <String, Double>();

    public void addDisplayCard(DisplayCard oneDisplayCard){
        displayCardMap.put(oneDisplayCard.getBrand() + ": " + oneDisplayCard.getmodelNumber(), oneDisplayCard.getmemorySize());
    }
}

public class DisplayCard {
    String brand;
    String modelNumber;
    double memorySize;

    //constructor method
    public DisplayCard(String brand, String modelNumber, double memorySize){
        this.brand = brand;
        this.modelNumber = modelNumber;
        this.memorySize = memorySize;
    }

    // getter method
    public String getBrand(){
        return brand;
    }

    public String getmodelNumber(){
        return modelNumber;
    }

    public double getmemorySize(){
        return memorySize;
    }
 }
```

But I get an error after I create a new item by the `addDisplayCard()`

```
public class TestComputerShop{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ComputerShop ashop = new ComputerShop();
        // call method
        ashop.addDisplayCard("ATI", "R9 390",6.0);

    } 
}
```

**So I want to know what is the problem.**

Should I create a new `DisplayCard` object first? Or the function is wrong at the beginning.

Comment: `addDisplayCard()` needs object of type display card and you're feeding in two strings

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan right, it's OOP basics. I think the question should be closed as trivial and not valuable

Comment: i can't see such option as trivial and not valueable

Comment: thank you very much, and I will work hard on OOP basics

Answer (score 2):

you need to create a new `DisplayCard` object, because your method requires one:

```
public class TestComputerShop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ComputerShop ashop = new ComputerShop();
        // call method
        ashop.addDisplayCard(new DisplayCard("ATI", "R9 390",6.0));

    } 
}
```

Another solution is to use method overloading inside the `ComputerShop`:

```
public class ComputerShop {

    Map <String, Double> displayCardMap = new HashMap <String, Double>();

    public void addDisplayCard(DisplayCard oneDisplayCard){
        displayCardMap.put(oneDisplayCard.getBrand() + ": " + oneDisplayCard.getmodelNumber(), oneDisplayCard.getmemorySize());
    }

    public void addDisplayCard(String brand, String modelNumber, double memorySize){
        this.addDisplayCard(new DisplayCard(brand, modelNumber, memorySize));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can decouple the new method from the original one as: `displayCardMap.put(brand+ ": " + modelNumber, memorySize);`

Comment: I have not suggested to decouple because I don't like duplicated code :-)